# Is the any possible to "return" a string value from constructor in Java?

Tags: java

It is all from a question my friend give me:

```
[???]
public class Exercise{
  public static void main(String[]arg){
    assert ("Hello "+new A()).equals("Hello world");
    }
  }
```

Is there any way to put something on the question mark areas to make it work? In my cognition, we can only define a method inside class A then call the method like new A().method() to return the String result? This is really confused me! Sorry but did not code Java for a long time haha.

Comment: You'd have to override `toString()` in `A` and make it return `"world"` for that particular assertion to pass.

Comment: The more conventional approach would be to define a field, say `String message = "world";` with a getter, and use it like `"Hello " + new A().getMessage()`

Comment: Constructor always returns a new instance of a given class. You can't make it return anything else. While @ernest_k 's suggestion would work in this case, it doesn't make a constructor return something else - it would create `A` and then call `toString()` on it (happens automatically when you try to concatenate non-String Object and String)

Answer (score 2):

When a parameter should be a String reference, but is a reference to another type of object, Java calls the object's **toString()** method to create a String and then uses the resulting String reference.

```
public class A {

    public static void main(String[]arg){
        assert ("Hello "+ new A()).equals("Hello world");
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "world";
    }
}
```

Since you are asking about something that can be written above the class, your friend might be referring to a annotation of some library such as [LOMBOK](https://projectlombok.org/). You can checkout few examples [here](http://www.javabyexamples.com/delombok-tostring/).

Answer (score 0):

A constructor, doesn't return.

However, if you really want to do that, you can do it like this:

1. You can add a callback as parameter and call it with expression that you want to return.
2. Provide a dummy string as parameter and overwrite its value inside the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the toString() method of Object's class. Something like this

```
public class Exercise{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Your String";
    }

  public static void main(String[]arg){
    assert ("Hello "+new A()).equals("Hello world");
    }

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

```java
class A {
  public String toString() {
    return "wo"+"rld";
  }
}
```

You are welcome.